# How to bridge two VMWare vsphere "VM Network" on two different site?

Tags: vmware-esxi, bridge, ethernet, vmware-vcenter, bridged-adapter

I got Two sites with some ESXi 6.7. Each site has its own IP address and I would like to bridge the "VM Network" on the distant site to the local "VM Network" so I could start a VM replicate on the distant site and it will be visible on the local "VM Network" without IP address changes.

I have no dedicated switch between the two sites, I use routers and telecom provided MPLS routed links with enough throughput.

My first through was about an openvpn link with TAP drivers so I can bridge an ethernet layer on each side, but I guess there may exist better solutions.

Comment: Why can't you simply route the connection? Bridging across WAN/VPN is no good idea generally.

Comment: I can not simply change IP address on some VM, because of exotic OS, or preconfigured appliances

Comment: There's no need to change IP addresses unless the ranges overlap.

Comment: The "VM Network" on both sit are not connected nor linked.